# Will a java exception terminate the whole java application?

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, jvm

I used to think that when an exception happened, the whole java application will be terminated. For example, I write a test function to test my idea.

```
public void test(){
    File fileDir=new File(sourceDataDir);
    if(fileDir.exists()){
        File[] files = fileDir.listFiles();
        for(int index=0 ; index<files.length ; index++){
            System.out.println("index = "+index);
            File file = files[index];
            if(index == 1)//delete a file to cause a FileNotFoundException
                file.delete();
            try {
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I delete a file to cause a `FileNotFoundException` manually. I used to think that the whole application will terminate when the  exception happened. But in fact, the application will continue reading the remaining files. So, my question is, in what condition an exception will cause the whole application to be terminated?

Answer (score 17):

If an exception is not caught with `catch`, the thread in which the exception occurred will be terminated. If no non-daemon threads remain the JVM will terminate. That's the only way how an exception might terminate a JVM. If you catch an exception it will never cause a JVM termination.

Comment: Does that mean it is good practice to have a catch-all block that catches the base `Exception` type i.e. `(catch (Exception e)){ }` so that we can ensure there's no JVM termination.

Comment: @AsifKamranMalick that requires an idea of how to proceed after you caught the exception. Otherwise, just terminating is already the cleanest solution. Mind that you can [install a handler for uncaught exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler)) to deal with them, without adding try-catch blocks to the code, which is preferable to implement a global strategy.

Answer (score 15):

> my question is ,in what condition ,a exception will cause the whole application to be terminated?

It won't ever.  Only System.exit() causes the whole program to terminate (and a JVM crash)

Think of an Exception and like a powerful `break;` which can break out of methods.  A break could result in a loop exiting and if the last loop in the only non daemon thread, the program will exit. But it doesn't cause it, even though it might be the last thing you see before you program dies.

Comment: Peter can you please check the answer I provided. I got a downvote and I don't know why.

Comment: Ok Thanks a lot for putting time in that. I will do take that into consideration. +1 for answer too. I guess I was trying to suggest the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

There are two main types of exceptions:

- Not runtime exceptions

It indicates the system is working properly. You must catch the exception or it won't compile. **It will never terminate** the application. If you want to terminate anyway, you have to call System.exit(ERROR_NUMBER) in the catch block or throw a runtime exception.

- Runtime exceptions

Indicates a system error (eg. application server misconfiguration). You don't have to catch it. **If you don't catch it, it terminates** the application or if you write a J2EE application the AS might handle it and continue your app.

Comment: actually I just tested it and RuntimeException does not terminate. Rather it bubbles up the exception to higher level callers (as long as you are not swallowing it up in a catch)

Comment: I think if no higher level caller catches it, the process will terminate (eg. NullPointerException). Application servers swallow these so enterprise application bugs don't crash the whole JavaEE server.

Comment: @Gadam How did you test it? Standalone Java process or an application container (eg. Tomcat)?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the deal with exceptions. They are of 2 types : `Checked` and `Unchecked`.

The `Checked` exceptions (all exceptions that are NOT subclasses of `RuntimeException`) must be handled in a `try-catch` or the code won't compile, like in the OPs question of `FileNotFoundException`. It's because of this forced handling that these exceptions *usually* do not terminate the app unless they are thrown up to the calling methods all the way up to the main() method, where they would stop the thread where they occurred.

The `Unchecked` exceptions (all exceptions that are subclasses of `RuntimeException`) need not be handled as these are from programming/data flaws (think divide by zero exception or trying to access a member of a null object etc.). These usually rip through the app and crash the thread they appear on, which could be your program on a single threaded execution.

Answer (score 1):

> So, my question is, in what condition, a exception will cause the
>   whole  application to be terminated?

See [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) for details on Exceptions. As for your problem FileNotFoundException is a checked Exception which means you need to handle it. Now you have to options

1. Catch the FileNotFoundException and handle(you can simply print stack trace and proceed)
2. or you can throw it to the parent(calling method)

In case 1 your java process will continue till it reaches the end(assuming no runtime Exceptions/errors occur).

In case 2 if you do not catch your FileNotFoundException even in the parent(calling function) and just throw it again and continue to do so, the exception will finally land up in the main() method. If even your main() method throws this exception JVM will simply shut down.

**Update for clarifying your comments:**

Catching an Exception is independent of whether Excpetion is catched ot not. Inc ase of uncahed Exception you can still catch it and let the program proceed. But that is not recommended because by definition of uncached Exception(which should not happen at all) you are not suppose to recover if uncached Exception occurs.

Consider following simple example

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        String s = null;
        System.out.println(s.length());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Catch runtime exception but not quite sure what to do with it");
    }

    System.out.println("Reached here even after uncatched Exception");
}
```

output is

```
Catch runtime exception but not quite sure what to do with it
Reached here even after uncatched Exception
```

So basically whenever Exception occurs if you do not catch it at any level from the point of origin, it will eventually propagate to main() and JVM will eventually shut down. If you do catch it(irrespective of catched or uncatched Exception) your program will proceed(output may not be as expected in case of uncatched Exceptions) and terminate.

Comment: So ,only unchecked exception may cause the main function to terminate,right?If it's an unchecked exception ,catching it or not becomes meaningless,so ,JVM doesn't impose us to catch or throw this exception explicitly, right?

Comment: unchecked exceptions are usually programming errors, which should not happen at all if implemented correctly (index out of bound, null pointer, class cast,...) and therefore the caller/ user usually cannot do anything about them. Even if the Exception is checked one and we simply throw it at each method it will eventually propagate to main method and JVM will shut down.

Comment: “So ,only unchecked exception may cause the main function to terminate,right?” *Uncatched* exceptions will cause the thread to terminate. While it’s seems to be impossible at the first glance that an exception other than RuntimeException or Error remains uncatched as the compiler forces catching checked exceptions, there are ways to produce them. E.g. the deprecated method `Thread.stop(Throwable)` allows to throw arbitrary undeclared throwables. You could also change a method to declare a checked exception *after* the caller has been compiled. And there are a few other corner cases.

Answer (score 0):

No. `Exception handlers` of java handles the abnormal execution of the program