# Need to move on after java error when Python script uses subprocess to run a java program

Tags: java, python, subprocess

In a python2.7 script, I'm using `subprocess.call` to run a java program like this:

```
java_command = "java -jar /path/to/java_program.jar %s %s >> %s" % (infile, outfile, logfile)
subprocess.call(java_command, shell=True)
...
#Do other stuff unrelated to this output
```

Most of the time, this works fine, but in some cases the java program errs:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at MyProgram.MainWindow.setProcessing(MainWindow.java:288)
```

The problem is that my python script is then stalled on the `subprocess.call()` line and can't do the "other stuff".

**Is there a way I can edit either the `java_command` I'm using or the way I'm using `subprocess` to continue the python script even when the java program hangs?**

<sub>Note that I can't modify the java program's code.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the [check_call](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) method from that same package:

```
try:
    status = subprocess.check_call(java_command, shell=True)
except CalledProcessError as e:
    # The exception object contains the return code and
    # other failure information.
    ... react to the failure and recover
```

Comment: Just tried this, to no avail.  I think the java program is not fully exiting somehow after its error.  When I run the same java command outside the script, from the command line, it gives the same answer but still doesn't return the command-line prompt until I Ctrl-C.

Comment: Seems like, based on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18607936/1623026), that the exception probably doesn't terminate the JVM, which means that I may be stuck here.

Comment: I see what you mean.  You're right: the Java program needs a particular flow handling to terminate on the exception.  You may want to spawn the process and continue, checking its status occasionally?